# Adding measure values based on date in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, iif

I am trying to create a measure in MDX with below logic -

```
IIF([Date].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue >= '2017-06-01', [Measure 1] + [Measure 2], [Measure 1] + [Measure 3])
```

The above expression is not working as it only performs one calculation for all the dates, but not on condition specified. Also, the calculation should work even if a Year is dragged on rows. I mean it should calculate measure1+measure2 for dates before June and other after June and returns both the sum again.

Can anyone provide any inputs how can I achieve that? Do I need to use something like SCOPE here?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to convert date to actual date using CDate? Is Date.Date member type of date?

Comment: Yes. I gave [Date].[Date].[&2016-06-01T00:00:00].MemberValue and it is recognizing the comparison. But the result is not as expected. Because the IIF condition is written on Date level, it is not working when I drag Year and try to see the results. Can anyone let me know how to achieve the result even if I drag Year, Month, Quarter also?

Comment: Why do you compare it by MemberValue if this is the same dimension? `[Date].[Date].CurrentMember >= [Date].[Date].[&2016-06-01T00:00:00]` should be enough. Also do you have any hierarchies? Is dimension set as datetime?

Comment: Yes. we have Date hierarchy in which year, quarter, month, week, date is there. If i don't give .Membervalue, the condition is not getting evaluated correctly. Yes, the dimension is set as datetime.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this calculation doesn't work is that MDX calculations are performed after data is aggregated, but the calculation as written needs to be performed at date level regardless of the level at which data is aggregated.

If you have a date hierarchy you can use something like the following calculation to aggregate over the leaf items relevant to the current filter/dimension selection:

```
SUM(DESCENDANTS([Date].[Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER, , LEAVES), IIF([Date].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue >= '2017-06-01', [Measure 1] + [Measure 2], [Measure 1] + [Measure 3]))
```

This will not be very efficient or fast, but if you don't need it to be blazing fast it might be sufficient.